# How to get in CAML (Sharepoint 2007) the same results as SPNavigation.QuickLaunch?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, caml

I have a website in Sharepoint.

To get a list of sites ordered by the exploration, that is to say, ordered by the user in the Sharepoint administration, I would write the following code:

```
 SPWeb web = CurrentSite.OpenWeb(currentSite);
 SPNavigation nav = web.Navigation;
 SPNavigationNodeCollection nodeColl = nav.QuickLaunch;
```

That is OK, but I need to do it with CAML. The only problem is that I don't know how to get the items ordered as the user did it, I get the items unordered or ordered by a column, I don't think there is a column for the user's order.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the navigation information is not stored with the pages in the library. The navigation can store more that just published pages, so the navigation had to be stored in it's own structure.

That means there is no content query for this.